# Agricultural depositary vs Agricultural depository

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-difference

I know that both words "**depositary**" and "**depository**" have a similar meaning:

- **Depository** - A place where something is deposited, as for storage, safekeeping or preservation; a repository.
- **Depositary** - A place where deposits or anything else is kept.

I know that both **Depositary bank** and **Depository bank** are correct and there's no difference except US vs UK.

But let's say I have a small building *(much larger than a shed)* where I keep my agricultural stuff and tools, what would the best name for that place be?

Maybe both these words aren't the right choice and I'm better off with some other one?

Comment: So... a large shed?

Comment: Something like it. A shed+a storage+a room where seedlings grow+a room where agrochemicals are.

Comment: What are you growing? On what scale?

Comment: tomatoes, cucumbers, onions, radish, cabbage, garlic, carrot and so on. In small amounts.

Comment: What is the main purpose of the building, and what does it look like? If it's a glass building mostly used for growing plants, then I would call it a greenhouse or maybe glasshouse. If it's more of a large storage space, especially if the building is fairly substantial, and especially if animals are ever kept in it, then I might call it a barn.

Comment: In my experience **depositary** is used mainly in legal contexts to refer to the *entity* to whom or to which something is entrusted, whereas **depository** is used in a wider range of contexts and refers to the *place* where something is held for safekeeping. US Federal regulations concerning banks refer to *depositaries* so it's not a US vs UK thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not choose to use either of your suggestions as they are not idiomatic, and other people might not understand what you mean. As for the word that is best to use, it would depend on the structure and purpose of the building.

- **Shed** - Usually a less substantial, simple building, often in someone's garden, usually not very big (although it could be), usually only contains one "room". A fairly generic term, it can be combined with other words to make it obvious what type of shed it is (tool shed - a tool store, garden shed - a shed with garden equipment in it, potting shed - a shed for planting things in, cowshed - a shed for sheltering/milking cows, bike shed - a shelter for parking bicycles in, etc.). For most people, a shed without context is a smallish wooden, single-roomed and storeyed structure in someone's garden.
- **Greenhouse** or **Glasshouse** - A predominantly glass structure, with a glass roof, usually with a single room (but not always) for growing plants in. It can be big or small, it is more about the construction material and purpose.
- **Barn** - Usually larger and more substantial than a shed, a building designed for storing food (often for feeding animals, e.g. grain or hay), animals or farming equipment, usually found on a farm (or something that used to be a farm). Often it will have one large room, that may be large vertically as well as horizontally, it can have multiple rooms. It will usually have one large door in it (a "barn door"). Mostly defined by its association with farming.
- **Outbuilding** or **Outhouse** - A generic term for a building near to a house that is not attached to the house. Usually a more substantial building than a shed, often larger than a shed, likely to have multiple rooms, but it doesn't have to. It doesn't say anything about its usage - it could contain a games room or some stables.
- **Garage** - A building designed for the storage of motor vehicles. Usually one room with (at least one) large door that a car, or other motor vehicle, can fit through. It doesn't have to be *used* for this purpose for it to be called a garage.
- **Storehouse** or **(something) store** - A generic term for a place meant/used for storing things in. If it is used for storing something specific then use (something) store (e.g. grain store or wood store).

Comment: It should be a shed+a storehouse